# How to merge properties of two JavaScript objects and prefer not null values?

Tags: javascript

Here are two objects:

```
const obj1 = {a: null, b: "b"} 
const obj2 = {a: "a", b: null}
```

How can I merge the two objects and get the following object?

```
{a: "a", b: "b"}
```

I can do this:

```
const merged = {...obj1, ...obj2}
```

But it returns this:

```
{ a: "a", b: null }
```

Is there a way to merge two objects while prefering not null (nor empty, undefined, etc.) values?

Comment: A for loop maybe, with an explicit `null` check?

Comment: Filter the objects before merging them

Comment: @kit good idea, however, that leads to loop twice.

Comment: I think this may be unavoidable

Comment: @Ele no it doesnt

Comment: @stetoc can you explain why not? `(:`

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function merge(obj1, obj2) {
  answer = {}
  for(key in obj1) {
    if(answer[key] === undefined || answer[key] === null)
      answer[key] = obj1[key];
  }
  for(key in obj2) {
    if(answer[key] === undefined || answer[key] === null)
      answer[key] = obj2[key];
  }
  return answer
}
```

Comment: `!answer[key]` will be true for values such as "false" or "0". I think a better approach would be to explicitly check for null values only.

Comment: Perhaps you could directly assign obj1 to answer and then only run the for loop for obj2?

Comment: You must declare your variables with `const`, `let` or `var`

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using **Lodash** [mergeWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith) for this:

```
const obj1 = {a: null, b: "b"} 
const obj2 = {a: "a", b: null}

const result = _.mergeWith({}, obj1, obj2,
  (a, b) => b === null ? a : undefined
)

// result: {a: "a", b: "b"}
```

Comment: Note: _.merge(obj1,obj2) will give the result if you have undefined attributes, not null ones.

Answer (score 2):

What about a simple `forEach()` loop on object `key`. It will work for both `null` and `undefined` values:

```js
const obj1 = {a: null, b: "b"};
const obj2 = {a: "a", b: null};
const merged = {};
Object.keys(obj1).forEach((key) => merged[key] = obj1[key] ? obj1[key] : obj2[key]);
console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
const obj1 = {a: null, b: "b"} 
const obj2 = {a: "a", b: null}
const obj3 = {}
for (var k in obj1) {
  obj3[k] = obj1[k] ? obj1[k] : obj2[k];
}
console.log(obj3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a modified version of the accepted answer:

```
function merge(obj1, obj2) {
  let merged = { ...obj1 }

  for (key in obj2) {
    if (merged[key] === undefined || merged[key] === null)
      merged[key] = obj2[key];
  }
  return merged
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured I could accomplish this by combining these libraries.

"[@ramda/mergedeepwith](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ramda/mergedeepwith)" is ported from [ramda](https://github.com/ramda/ramda).

"[flat](https://github.com/hughsk/flat)" is Flatten/unflatten nested Javascript objects.

```
yarn add @ramda/mergedeepwith flat ramda
```

This is workaround.

```js
import { default as flat } from "flat";
import mergeDeepWith from "@ramda/mergedeepwith";
import * as R from "ramda";
const obj1 = {
  a: null,
  b: "bbb",
  c: {
    "c-1": "cccc",
  },
  d: [
    {
      "d-1": "ddd-1",
    },
    {
      "d-2": null,
    },
    {
      "d-3": [0, 1, "a", 100], // omit 0
    },
  ],
};
const obj2 = {
  a: "aaa",
  b: null,
  c: {
    "c-1": null,
  },
  d: [
    {
      "d-1": null,
    },
    {
      "d-2": "ddd-2",
    },
    {
      "d-3": ["b", "c"],
    },
  ],
};
const flattenedObj1 = flat.flatten(obj1);
const flattenedObj2 = flat.flatten(obj2);
const mergedObj = R.mergeDeepWith(
  (x, y) => {
    if (x) return x;
    if (y) return y;
    return null;
  },
  flattenedObj2,
  flattenedObj1
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(flat.unflatten(mergedObj), null, 2));
```

Output is here.

```js
$ node index.js
{
  "a": "aaa",
  "b": "bbb",
  "c": {
    "c-1": "cccc"
  },
  "d": [
    {
      "d-1": "ddd-1"
    },
    {
      "d-2": "ddd-2"
    },
    {
      "d-3": [
        "b",
        "c",
        "a",
        100
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This workaround was mashed up as  [@nap5/use-merge](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nap5/use-merge) Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function omitNull (obj) {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj);
  const _obj = {};
  for (const key of keys) {
    const value = obj[key];
    if (value !== null) {
      _obj[key] = value;
    }
  }
  return _obj;
}

const merged = {
  ...omitNull(obj1),
  ...omitNull(obj2)
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = {};
for(key in obj1){
    result[key] = obj1[key] === null ? obj2[key] : obj1[key];
}
```

this merges two objects in one loop

Comment: does not handle the case when obj2 has a key that is not in obj1

Comment: in example there are two objects of same type, only with different fields, that's what he asked, that's what I created

Comment: he never asked to merge two objects with identical keys, he just said to merge two objects. Also he mentioned the undefined, every key that is not in an obj will return undefined. Therefore if you have something in obj2 that is not is obj1, this value will return indefined, so your code is not handling it.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function that gets an array of objects as a parameter.

This way, no matter how many objects you have, you will get the result of them merged together excluding the undefined and null values. Just send them as an array.

There you pass all your objects, map them, then iterate through their key,values with `for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj))` and exclude the ones that are `undefined` or `null`

See below

```js
const obj1 = {
  a: null,
  b: "goodb",
  c: 0,
}
const obj2 = {
  a: "gooda",
  b: null,
  c: undefined
}

function cleanObjects(arr) {
  let o = {}
  arr.map((obj) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      typeof value === 'undefined' || value === null ?
       delete obj[key] : o[key] = value;
    }
  })
  return o;
}
const result = cleanObjects([obj1, obj2])
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the Javascript ObjectConstructor itself. Add a function `merge`,
This overrides the next non-null value and adds all the objects' properties to one single object.

```js
/* @/utils.js */

Object.merge = function (...objs) {
  const obj = {};
  objs.reduce((prevObj, currentObj) => {
    if (typeof prevObj === 'object' && typeof currentObj === 'object') Object.entries(currentObj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      obj[k] = v === null || v === undefined
        ? prevObj[k]
        : v;
    });
    return obj;
  }, {});
  return obj;
};

/* @/app.js */

Object.merge(a,b,c,...z);
```

```js
Object.merge = function (...objs) {
  const obj = {};
  objs.reduce((prevObj, currentObj) => {
    if (typeof prevObj === 'object' && typeof currentObj === 'object') Object.entries(currentObj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
      obj[k] = v === null || v === undefined
        ? prevObj[k]
        : v;
    });
    return obj;
  }, {});
  return obj;
}

const john = {
name: 'John Doe',
age: 40,
heigth: '5.3ft'
}

const jane = {
name: 'Jane Doe',
age: null,
heigth: '4.1ft'
}

const mark = {
name: 'Mark',
age: 35,
heigth: null
}

const ghost = {
name: null,
age: null,
heigth: null,
planet: 'unknown'
}

const noname = {
name: null,
age: 100,
heigth: '100ft',
planet: '100M-E'
}

console.log(Object.merge(john,jane,mark,ghost,noname))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function merge(obj1, obj2) {
  if (!obj1 && !obj2) return null
  if (!obj1) return obj2;
  if (!obj2) return obj1;
  result = {}
  const keys = [...new Set([...Object.keys(obj1), ...Object.keys(obj2)])];
  keys.forEach(key => {
     result[key] = obj1[key] || obj2[key]
  })
  return result
}

console.log(merge(null, undefined))
console.log(merge({ a: 1}, null))
console.log(merge(null, { b : 2}))
console.log(merge(null, { }))
console.log(merge({a: 1, b : null, c : undefined, d: 'd'}, { b : 2, c: 5, d: null}))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj1 = {
  a: null,
  b: "goodb",
  c: 0,
  d: 133,
f: null
}
const obj2 = {
  a: "gooda",
  b: null,
  e: 1,
  c: undefined
}

function cleanObjects(arr) {
  let o = {}
  arr.map((obj) => {
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
      typeof value === 'undefined' || value === null ?
        delete obj[key] : o[key] = value;
    }
  })
  return o;
}
const result = cleanObjects([obj1, obj2])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, someone should mention the [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)

So for top-level properties you can choose the not-nullish one:

```
const obj1 = { a: null, b: "b" } 
const obj2 = { a: "a", b: null }
const obj3 = { foo: Infinity }

let merge = (...objects) => 
  objects
    .reduce((result, next) => ({ ...result, ...Object.entries(next)
      .reduce((resultingEntries, [key, value]) => ({ ...resultingEntries, [key]: value ?? result[key] }), {})}))

merge(obj1, obj2, obj3)
// {a: "a", b: "b", foo: "c"}
```

If you also want to copy deeper properties, things start to get REALLY ugly:

```
let merge2 = (...objects) => 
      objects
        .reduce((result, next) => ({ ...result, ...Object.entries(next)
          .reduce((resultingEntries, [key, value]) => ({ ...resultingEntries, [key]: 
            result && result[key] && typeof result[key] === 'object' // <- null unsafe here
              ? merge3(...objects.map(o => o && o[key]))
              : value ?? result[key] // <- to here?
          }), {})}))
```

Perhaps better to extract it to a function

```
const getProps = (key, ...objects) => objects.filter(isntNullOrUndefined).map(o => o[key]).filter(isntNullOrUndefined)
const isntNullOrUndefined = x => x !== null && x !== undefined

const merge2 = (...objects) => 
  objects
    .filter(isntNullOrUndefined)
    .reduce((acc, obj) => ({
      ...acc,
      ...Object
        .keys(obj)
        .filter(key => !(key in acc))
        .filter(key => isntNullOrUndefined(obj[key]))
        .reduce((acc2, key) => ({
          ...acc2,
          [key]: typeof obj[key] === 'object'
            ? merge2(...getProps(key, ...objects))
            : getProps(key, ...objects)[0]
        }), {})
    }), {})
```

The next step is to do it with iterators, which might be slicker than `reduce` using the `??` operator.